# Debian installer missing non-free firmware; how to correct?

Tags: debian-installer

Tried to install but it said its missing the non free firmware. i already tried burning the ISO with DD enabled. Ive tried google but i need more simple answers (ie in installer, first open console by pressing KEY COMBO and put command JERRYSEINFELD to get the missing stuff and type EXIT to exit the console)

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way for you is to follow [Debian installation instructions](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/ch06s04):

> Official installation images do not include non-free firmware. The
> most common method to load such firmware is from some removable medium
> such as a USB stick. Alternatively, unofficial installation images
> containing non-free firmware can be found at
> https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/.

Just download the `.iso` file containing the non-free firmwares from the link above, re-create your installation media and try again.